# CRM 2011+ SSRS Report + Currency Formatting

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a ssrs report in CRM online using BIDS.
Generated well but those currency field which is negative shows on the report with bracket.

All positive currency fields showing well on the report but negative currency field is showing with bracket like  "(value)" on the report.

May do this like  "-$value" or something else.

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the settings inside the placeholder properties, right click on the field in Design mode and you can choose also the format for negative values

[image]

Comment: I have done this..in all currency fields on the report..

But all currency fields having same problem..if any field's value is negative then it shows with bracket..

so it seems me that it is related to whole report properties..

Comment: This is related to symbol selected. Here US(English) is selected that is why it is taking the setting if US(English)...

May be this case..not sure..:)

Answer (score 3):

You can try setting the textbox **Format** property using an explicit format string, something like:

```
$#,#;-$#,#;$0
```

To edit a textbox **Format** property click on the textbox then edit the **Format** value in the **Properties** tab:

[image]

Comment: How to do this??

And where to do this??  I am using BIDS...:)

Comment: I've added a screenshot to the answer; I don't know how to be more explicit than this.

Comment: @IanPreston right, the format can be applied also to the textbox, not only to the placeholder

Comment: Sorry, due to some reason that screen shot did not appeared  on my screen..
BTW..i did this as suggested but still negative currency is showing with brackets.
This is related to symbol selected. Here US(English) is selected that is why it is taking the setting if US(English)... May be this case..not sure..:)

Comment: By directly adding this format in property 'Format' or
doing this same by Text Box Properties..
Both are same...

I am showing a field which is sum of some other fields...
I am summing this itself on the report..and this SUM field is showing correctly as '$-value'..and i looked into the 'Format' property and it reflects the same **'$'#,0;'$'-#,0**..

Don't understand the concept..:(

Comment: This is fantastic! For some reason, setting in the UI wasn't working for me. This fixed the problem though. Thanks!